# I cant render functional component withing FlatList

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-native-flatlist

I spent too much time on this problem, and I dont see where is my error. I have a functional component `CommentsList` where I want to render list of comments. Additionally, I also have `Comments.js` which is functional component, which will render details of the comment itself. Here is the code of `CommentsList.js`:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import { View,
        Text,
        FlatList,
        ScrollView} from 'react-native';

import Comment from './Comment';

import firebase from 'firebase';
require('firebase/firestore');

const CommentsList = ({userId, postId}) => {

  const [comments, setComments] = useState([])

  useEffect(() => {
      getComments();
  }, [])

  const getComments = () => {
          firebase.firestore()
              .collection('comments')
              .orderBy('creation', 'desc')
              .get()
              .then((snapshot) => {
                  let comments = snapshot.docs.map(doc => {
                      const data = doc.data();
                      const id = doc.id;
                      return { id, ...data }
                  })
                  setComments(comments)
              });
  }

  return (
      <ScrollView>
          <FlatList
              numColumns={1}
              horizontal={false}
              data={comments}
              keyExtractor={item => item.id}
              renderItem={({item}) => <Comment comment={item} /> }
          />
      </ScrollView>
  )
}


export default CommentsList;
```

As you can see, within `FlatList`, I am trying to render `Comment` component. Here is my very simplified version of `Comment.js`:

```
import React from 'react';
import { View, Text} from 'react-native';

const Comment = () => {
   return (
     <View>
         <Text>
             Other comment
          </Text>
      </View>
    )
}

export default Comment;
```

Obviously, I want to add other pieces to `Comment.js` but for the time being I really cant. I have the following error: `Error: Text strings must be rendered within a <Text> component.` When I change my `Comment.js` component to :

```
import React from 'react';
    import { View, Text} from 'react-native';
    
    const Comment = () => {
       return (
             <Text>
                 Other comment
              </Text>
        )
    }
    
    export default Comment;
```

it all renders perfectly fine and I see the comment, but obviously I need the `View` element to wrap my component, because it is not just a text which I want to show. I want to show names, time, etc. But I cant because I always have `Error: Text strings must be rendered within a <Text> component.` error showing. I tried simplifying my `Comment.js` component again and again, just to make it work and this is very simplified version, yet it does not render.

Any suggestions will be more than welcome, as I spent too much time on this problem.

Comment: Nothing seems to be wrong here, the simplified version that you have provided, is that the same that throwing the error ?

Comment: @GuruparanGiritharan yes, it is. I will restart my computer, and reinstall expo then....

Comment: no need to reinstall, check whether you have spaces in between, or type like (<View><Text>something here</Text></View>)

Comment: when I typed return (<View><Text>Other comment</Text></View>); it worked fine and I see the comment now. So basically it didnt like my identation?

Comment: Yeah some issue with the spacing you had, or maybe there was an blank string in the middle

Answer (score 0):

It looks correct code and should work.

One thing which you can do is to do formatting of the code, to avoid any spacing issues.